# What I should use instead of resolvers?

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

As u already know the Local resolvers are deprecated so we can't use it as a perspective way to handling REST cache. What we should use instead of resolvers?
'field policies' are not good for that at all. Let's imagine... You have two different client queries: getBooks and getBook. Each query getting data from the rest API. Somehow we need to handle the situation when we already got the data from getBooks and runing another query getBook. getBook should not make a request because the data were already cached. We did that in resolvers before it was deprecated. We were just checking the cache and return the data if it already exists in the cache if not did a request. How we can handle this in current circumstances?

Comment: Any way to add some code example? (It is hard to understand your Q). Also, maybe divide your text into paragraphs (More readable).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it's a bit not what I meant. Here is a code example:

```
export const getBooks = gql`
    query getBooks () {
        getBooks ()
            @rest(
                type: "Book"
                path: "books"
                endpoint: "v1"
            ) {
            id
            title
            author
        }
    }
`

export const getBook = gql`
    query getBook ($id: Int!) {
        getBook (id: $id)
            @rest(
                type: "Book"
                path: "book/{args.id}"
                endpoint: "v1"
            ) {
            id
            title
            author
        }
    }
`
```

So we have two different queries. The goal is when we run both in turn the getBook should not make a REST request because we already have the same data in the cache since we get it from getBooks. Before resolvers were deprecated we handle it in resolvers. Like: if this ID is not exist in the cache just make a request if exist give me data from the cache. How we can do that now?

As u can see fetchPolicy it's completely different.
Local fields it's also not good because it's something about fields not about the whole entity.

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.